# Spring HTTP Invoker Null Pointer

Tags: spring-boot, httpinvoker

I have two Spring Boot (1.5.6) applications using Http Invoker (one as Server, and one as Client side).
The Server HTTP Invoker is deployed on a remote server, and i am running the client side on my local machine and trying to invoke (call) the server.
The Return type of the HTTP Invoker Server operation is List containing HashMap with properties.
I noticed a strange issue. 
When trying to invoke the Server HTTP Invoker which is deployed on a remote server, i get a null pointer exception.
When trying to invoke the Server HTTP Invoker (when it is running on my local machine - and also client is running on my local machine) everything is OK.
Can someone help me with my problem?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, this one is regarding the Spring HTTP Invoker and it's behavior

Comment: But it is the only answer we can get without code and stacktrace